# How to specify RULES in main body

Tags: spacing, theorems

I want to write RULES in main body, how to write the correct TeX code that guarantees a little larger space before and after RULES like this.

[image: sample image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I added the `theorem` tag as your rules are a theorem-like element. If you disagree, feel free to remove the tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A from-scratch definition for such "RULE"s is easy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcounter{rules}
\newenvironment{rules}
  {\par\medskip\refstepcounter{rules}%
   \normalfont RULE~\therules.\quad\itshape\ignorespaces}
  {\par\medskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{rules}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{rules}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{rules}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{rules}
\lipsum*[4]
\end{document}
```

The `rules` environment inserts a gap above & below equivalent to `\medskip` (which is `6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt` or `\medskipamount`). A gap of `\quad` (or `1em`) is inserted between the `RULE #.` and the starting *italicized* text. It can also be referenced using `\label`-`\ref`, if needed.

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

---

Indentation of the first paragraph of the `rule` environment can be avoided by using `\noindent`:

```
%...
\newenvironment{rules}
  {\par\medskip\refstepcounter{rules}%
   \noindent\normalfont RULE~\therules.\quad\itshape\ignorespaces}
  {\par\medskip}
%...
```

For more elaborate paragraph indentation management, consider using the [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip).

Comment: It is a great answer. I want to know how to eliminate the indent (i.e., space before "RULE #").

Comment: Oh, I know, just use \noindent before "\normalfont RULE~\therules.\quad\itshape\ignorespaces"

Answer (score 8):

There's `\newtheorem` which, with the help of `amsthm` can be easily customized. This might seem more complicated than defining the environment "by hand", but it better ensures uniformity between the various parts of a document; `\topsep` is the space LaTeX uses before the list environments, for instance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{rule}
  {\topsep}  % space above
  {\topsep}  % space below
  {\itshape} % body font
  {}         % indent amount (empty = no indent)
  {}         % theorem head font (empty = normal font)
  {.}        % punctuation after theorem head
  { }        % space after theorem head
  {}         % theorem head spec (empty = normal)

\theoremstyle{rule}
\newtheorem{RULE}{RULE}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{RULE}\label{periscope}
\lipsum[2]
\end{RULE}

Here's the number:~\ref{periscope}. \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

All `\newtheorem` declarations after `\theoremstyle{rule}` will inherit the same parameters defined in the style. The predefined styles are `plain`, `definition` (upright body font) and `remark`, but one can build new ones as shown.

[image]